# Javascript cross-domain requests to a Glassfish 4 server?

Tags: java, javascript, servlets, glassfish, cors

I have a Glassfish 4 webserver (running locally atm for testing) with a servlet, need to be able to request a string from a different domain using Javascript.

Searching for a solution, people suggest enabling CORS on my web server, by creating a Filter class (implementing ContainerRequestFilter and ContainerResponseFilter).
I've tried creating such a class, but the client still gets the same error; "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource".

What am I doing wrong?

Code:

**class: CrossDomainFilter.java**

```
package server;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

@Provider
@CORSBinding
public class CrossDomainFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter, ContainerResponseFilter {
    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext request) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("filter(request) called !!");

        request.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        request.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                "Authorization");
        if (request.getMethod().equals("OPTIONS")) {
            System.out.println("OPTIONS is requested!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
        }
        if (request.getMethod().equals("GET")) {
            System.out.println("GET is requested!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
        }
        if (request.getMethod().equals("POST")) {
            System.out.println("POST is requested!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
        }
        if (request.getMethod().equals("DELETE")) {
            System.out.println("DELETE is requested!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
        }
        if (request.getMethod().equals("PUT")) {
            System.out.println("PUT is requested!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext arg0,
            ContainerResponseContext arg1) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("filter(request, response) called !!");
    }
}
```

**Javascript function making the request**
function httpRequest(url) {

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", url, false);
request.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
request.send(null);
return (request.status == 404) ? url + " not found!" : request.responseText;
```

}

**EDIT:**
Ended up using this: https://bitbucket.org/thetransactioncompany/cors-filter
I can now make javascript requests to my server cross-domain. But I would still like to understand what's wrong with my previous attempts...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding headers to the `Request` instead of the `Response`. `Request` is the data from the client to the server while the `Response` is the data from the server to the client. The headers need to be set by the server to tell the browser that the resource is allowed (or not) be access by a particular domain.

With your example, you're adding the headers to the response before dispatch by the servlet. You also don't need the header in the javascript request.

Here's a pretty good resource with more detail on the different headers and use cases. http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/